# Unable to get Monodevelop using FlatPak in Ubuntu to run ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, monodevelop, flatpak

When trying to launch and ASP.NET site in Monodevelop (installed via Flatpak, latest stable version) I get the following error when it tries to start up the browser:

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04 (XFCE based version of Ubuntu)

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): ApplicationName='xdg-open', CommandLine='http://127.0.0.1:8080', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x001ee] in :0
```

I've been all over the net trying to figure this one out, but I haven't worked out why it can't see the xdg-open utility.  I tried doing a re-install of the xdg-utilities using apt-get but no luck.  Anyone else run into this and have a work around or a fix?

Edit:  You can go to http://127.0.0.1:8080 or whatever your url is if you changed it from default and still see the site.  It just won't come up automatically in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have the same environment as yours and having the same problem. Just tried something randomly and somehow it worked. It's not much of a fix but a workaround that might do until this is addressed. Try this, while still running your program, just open your browser and type
**http://127.0.0.1:8080**
Hopefully, that should work. If it works, I guess the only inconvenience will be that you get to do stuff manually.

Comment: Yes I did find that does work, I meant to come back and update this.  Hopefully they will fix this in the future for convenience.